# Changing the background of login & logout button of facebook iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

I'm using the facebook login with iOS following steps in this link [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-tutorial)

and it works well with me. I noticed that the login & logout background of the view is blue as the default of facebook. look to this image

[image]

Is it possible to change the color to be white, transparent or add background image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Icon_login_facebook may be your custom image with needed size

```
_loginView.frame = CGRectMake(320/2 - 93/2, self.view.frame.size.height -200, 93, 93);

for (id loginObject in _loginView.subviews)
{
    if ([loginObject isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        UIButton * loginButton =  loginObject;
        UIImage *loginImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon_login_facebook"];
        loginButton.alpha = 0.7;
        [loginButton setBackgroundImage:loginImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [loginButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [loginButton sizeToFit];
    }
    if ([loginObject isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
        UILabel * loginLabel =  loginObject;
        loginLabel.text = @"";
        loginLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}
```